# Help with " in case of"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can I say" in case of cleaning your room, it will look nice." ?
Or should" in case of " be only followed by a noun?

Answer (score 1):

"In case of" should be followed by a noun or noun phrase.  But even if we use a noun in your sentence, it still doesn't work.

"In case of cleanliness, your room will look nice" is *grammatically* valid, but semantically nonsense as it's not only a tautology, and but "in case of ____, _____" describes a something that is a contingency plan.  "Your room will look nice" is not a contingency plan.  It is not a plan at all.

I believe the word you are looking for is "If", as in: "If you clean your room, it will look nice."  This is a perfectly natural sentence.